# Symfony 3 - Twig - Access to a field Entity from OneToMany field?

Tags: symfony

I have a User entity and a Role entity.
A user has a role (his ID) thanks to a ManyToOne field.

In my controller, I retrieve all users who do not have the USER role.
In my twig view, I want to display the information of each of these users as well as their role (the name of the role).

Clearly, how can I access the "RoleName" field of the Role entity from my twig user?

I've :

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nom complet
            </th>
            <th>
                Mail
            </th>
            <th>
                Role
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for unUser in listeUser %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{unUser.nom}} {{unUser.prenom}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{unUser.mail}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{unUser.role}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

And I would like something like {{ unUser.role.nomRole }}

Comment: What's wrong with `{{ unUser.role.nomRole }}` ?

Comment: You didn't close the `for` loop by the way

Comment: Oh okay, In fact my code was an example, I had to do manipulations in my controller before. And I did not know that {{unUser.role.RoleName}} was possible. But since it is, my question no longer makes sense! Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

For show this variable : unUser.role."nomRole"

You need add leftJoin "role" in your sql request in your repository.